# How to blit a tranparent image in pygame to make an alpha "cut-out"

Tags: python, pygame

Given a pygame Surface filled with some pixels, I want to programmatically make an alpha-channel "window" in that image (such that the background shows through).

[image]

Obviously I realise that this can be trivially done with a bitmap editor, the point of the question is to do this on-the-fly as part of a different, more-complex operation.

So I made a sprite that switches between the "full-red" and "red-with-hole" images, and tried to dynamically make the bitmap-window by blitting a fully-transparent image onto the base-bitmap.

I think what is happening, is that PyGame is not painting the fully-transparent pixels because, well they're transparent!  Is there a way to blit them such that the window is made?

I tried adding `pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN` [and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601776/what-do-the-blend-modes-in-pygame-mean) (as per the suggestion in [Need to blit transparency on a surface in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395087/need-to-blit-transparency-on-a-surface-in-pygame) ), but failed to achieve the desired result.

All I ever get is a black square, centred in the red, rather than a window to the background.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
FPS           = 60

# background colours
INKY_BLACK    = (128, 128, 128)

class HoleSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        # Make a full-image (no hole)
        self.base_image = pygame.Surface( ( 32, 32 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.base_image.fill( ( 255,0,0 ) )
        # Make an image with a see-through window
        self.hole_image = pygame.Surface( ( 32, 32 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.hole_image.fill( ( 255,0,0 ) )
        self.hole       = pygame.Surface( ( 10, 10 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.hole.fill( ( 0, 0, 0, 255 ) ) # transparent
        self.hole_image.blit( self.hole, [ 10,10, 10,10 ] ) # punch the middle out?
        # sprite housekeeping
        self.image  = self.base_image
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WINDOW_WIDTH  // 2   # centred
        self.rect.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT // 2
        self.last   = 0

    def update( self ):
        time_ms = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        # FLip the images each second
        if ( time_ms - self.last > 1000 ):
            if ( self.image == self.hole_image ):
                self.image = self.base_image
            else:
                self.image = self.hole_image
            self.last = time_ms


### MAIN
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Hole Srite Test")

anims = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
holey = HoleSprite( )
anims.add( holey )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done  = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Repaint the screen
    anims.update()
    WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
    anims.draw( WINDOW )

    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( FPS )

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: you need `(0,0,0,0)`, not `(0,0,0,255)`. You can use [pygame.draw.rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) to draw small rectangle with color `(0,0,0,0)` directly on red surface.

Comment: see [pygame transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you need `(0,0,0,0)` instead of `(0,0,0,255)`

Second: you have to use `fill(color, rect)` to create transparent hole directly in red rectangle.

```
self.hole_image.fill( (0, 0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 10, 10) )
```

Or you can draw transparent rectangle directly in red surface

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.hole_image, (0, 0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 10, 10) )
```

When you blit transparent image on full color image then it doesn't replace pixels but  it mix both colors (transparent and full) and you get full color.

`blit()` has flags `BLEND_ADD`, `BLEND_SUB`, `BLEND_MULT`, etc. and maybe using one of this flag you could replace pixels but I never tried it.

Other information: [pygame transparency](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Full code:

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
FPS           = 60

# background colours
INKY_BLACK    = (128, 128, 128)

class HoleSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        # Make a full-image (no hole)
        self.base_image = pygame.Surface( ( 32, 32 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.base_image.fill( ( 255,0,0 ) )
        # Make an image with a see-through window

        self.hole_image = pygame.Surface( ( 32, 32 ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.hole_image.fill( ( 255,0,0 ) )
        self.hole_image.fill( (0, 0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 10, 10) )
        # OR
        #pygame.draw.rect(self.hole_image, (0, 0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 10, 10) )

        # sprite housekeeping
        self.image  = self.base_image
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WINDOW_WIDTH  // 2   # centred
        self.rect.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT // 2
        self.last   = 0

    def update( self ):
        time_ms = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        # FLip the images each second
        if ( time_ms - self.last > 1000 ):
            if ( self.image == self.hole_image ):
                self.image = self.base_image
            else:
                self.image = self.hole_image
            self.last = time_ms


### MAIN
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Hole Srite Test")

anims = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
holey = HoleSprite( )
anims.add( holey )

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done  = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Repaint the screen
    anims.update()
    WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
    anims.draw( WINDOW )

    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( FPS )

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @furas.  Do you think the `rect()` would be more efficient than the `blit()` ?.  I guess I should profile it.

Comment: I think it may not make differenct in small game. You create hole_image only once and later you can use Sprite and Group functions to easily display on screen - `group.draw()` . And you can always easily use different image.